# Match Username (field from mysql table) To Session ID In PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

How do i do it? I'v tried all different ways but I just cant do it!

Basically, im trying to pull out information from the "starters table" and display only the logged in users data.

Here is the code which gives me an error message in which I cannot solve:

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once '../database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['myusername'];
}
?>

<?php
include '../database.php';

$userid = $_SESSION["myusername"];

#the where clause is where im stuck at the moment!

Line 50:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Recipename, Ingredients, Method, Time FROM starters WHERE username = $_SESSION['myusername']");

echo "<table border='0'><table border width=65%> <tr><th>Recipie Name</th><th>Ingredients</th><th>Method</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Recipename']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Ingredients']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Method']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Time']. 'minutes'."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

        ?>
</table>
```

the error message i get is the following:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/jahedhus/public_html/cook/usersloggedin/starters.php on line 50
```

line 50 is the select statement!
I would really appreciate your help,
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the username in quotes:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Recipename, Ingredients, Method, Time FROM starters WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['myusername']}'");
```

Additionally, you're trusting that `$_SESSION['myusername']` is a valid username (not some string of attach SQL). If you don't know that data is safe, you need to at least [escape the data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @webarto Ah, yes. Thanks. Or just concatenate it.

Comment: you could, but wrapping in {} doesn't hurt also :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Recipename, Ingredients, Method, Time FROM starters WHERE username = $_SESSION['myusername']");
```

with this one:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Recipename, Ingredients, Method, Time FROM starters WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['myusername'] . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the quotes is that they will get all gummed up, i'd seperate them either:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Recipename, Ingredients, Method, Time FROM starters WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['myusername']);
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Recipename, Ingredients, Method, Time FROM starters WHERE username = '$_SESSION[myusername]'");
```